# Problems Rounding off Zeros from Calculations

Tags: python-3.x

So I have encountered a problem while trying to run a calculation;
While running my code, it automatically rounds off any zero's, but I wish to keep them as part of the answer.

For example, my calculation returns `10.4`, when I want it to return `10.40`

Is there any way to remedy this?? 
Here is what I have so far:

```
balance = ((len(last_name) * 0.05) + 10)
```

Comment: If the real number is 10.40, then it's a formatting problem, not a rounding problem.

Comment: Trailing zeros, like leading zeros, have absolutely no meaning in an actual **number**. They only have meaning when you turn them into a string. You'll want to look into the string [format syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed before, 10.4 and 10.40 are the same number, so there is nothing being rounded off. If you want to display your float with additional zeroes, you can do it this way:

```
print("{:.2f}".format(balance))
```